# É possível utilizar o .htaccess com o IIS?

Tags: htaccess, iis

É possível eu utilizar o `.htaccess` com o IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível parcialmente com [utilitários específicos](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/), mas a recomendação é fazer uma [conversão e usar o `web.config`](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é o equivalente para ele. Tem [conversor on-line](http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx) ([outro](http://www.htaccesstowebconfig.com/)), mas não sei a qualidade deles. Dependendo do que for fazer tem [ferramenta oficial](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).